# pass same method to multiple decorator functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a method like so

```
def update_count(target, value, initiator):
  target.count = len(target.collection)
```

However, I have three decorator functions I wish to apply it to

```
@event.listens_for(MyClass.collection, 'append')
@event.listens_for(MyClass.collection, 'remove')
@event.listens_for(MyClass.collection, 'set')
```

Instead of copying the whole method below each decorator, what is a pythonic way to pass `update_count` to each of the `event.listens_for` decorator methods as a reference?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest:

```
@event.listens_for(MyClass.collection, 'append')
@event.listens_for(MyClass.collection, 'remove')
@event.listens_for(MyClass.collection, 'set')
def update_count(target, value, initiator):
    target.count = len(target.collection)
```

i.e, just put the decorators one after the other before `def`.

Of course, this may cause overhead, e.g if each decorator wraps the decorated function into another -- but if you can't fix the decorator, then you can't avoid that overhead.  If you **can** change the decorator, then a `listen_multi` variant thereof, that takes all events being listened for in a single gulp, might no doubt offer much better performance.

Comment: ah, totally forgot you could do that. Thank you sir